# C# Create Excel (Done) then show/open it? Help

Tags: c#, excel

I can create an excel and save it, however I would prefer to show the document! Any help would be great!! Thanks

```
Excel.Application   xlApp;
Excel.Workbook      xlWorkBook;
Excel.Worksheet     xlWorkSheet;

object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp       = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook  = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);

xlWorkSheet         = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Sheets["Sheet1"];
xlWorkSheet.Name    = "Exported Data";

xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "Demo";
xlWorkSheet             = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);

xlWorkBook.SaveAs("Filename.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);

xlWorkSheet = null;
xlWorkBook  = null;
xlApp       = null;
GC.Collect();
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can always display the xlApp using

```
xlApp.Visible = true;
```

Comment: Where is this file temporally saving ?? Are we need to delete the file which created later?

Comment: @devan it will not be saved anywhere.

Answer (score 7):

Insert this line `xlApp.Visible = true;`, and don't call `Close()` and `Quit()` methods